# C-like character addition in Java?

Tags: java, character

I just switched from C++ to Java. I'm trying to write a program that loops from 0 to some number less than 26. I want to get the letter of the alphabet that corresponds with that number.

For example, iteration 0 would be "A". Iteration 2 would be "B". 3 would be "C".

In C++, I could just do 'A' + i and convert it back to a char. Is there a simple way of doing this in Java?

Comment: You can do: for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) { ... }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `char` primitive type you can do the same thing.

```
char capitalA = 'A';
char capitalZ = (char)(capitalA + 25);
```

Notice the second line where I had to cast back down to char (from int) as the addition operation is automatically widened to an int.

Comment: Cool. I need to pop that char into a function that takes a String, though. I can't seem to get char to convert to string. Do I need to write another version of the function that takes a char, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. I stuck a Character.toString in front of it. Gawd it's all ugly :(

Comment: actually, ""+char will convert the char type to string.

Comment: You can also use the static method [`String.valueOf(char c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29)

Answer (score 2):

Hope below code can help u,

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        System.out.println((char)(i+'A'));
    }
```